# Get DB DataType ServiceStack Ormlite

Tags: database, types, ormlite-servicestack

Is there a way from a POCO class to get the actual DB Data Type of the various properties?
For Example: Let's assume the POCO class

```
public  class Product : IHasId<int>
{
    [Alias("id")]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description  { get; set; }
}
```

The fields Name and Description could be as Varchar(n) or Text in the Database(SQL Server). Is it possible to get the actual DB DataType from the POCO properties?

Answer (score 3):

OrmLite expects the underlying RDBMS Schema column definition to be what's specified in the TypeConverter which you can fetch with:

```
var converter = OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider.GetStringConverter();
var columnDef = converter.ColumnDefinition;
```

To get the actual Column Definition you'd need to use custom SQL to query SQL Server

```
var sql = @"select COLUMN_NAME, data_type + 
    case
        when data_type like '%text' or data_type like 'image' or data_type like 'sql_variant' or data_type like 'xml'
            then ''
        when data_type = 'float'
            then '(' + convert(varchar(10), isnull(numeric_precision, 18)) + ')'
        when data_type = 'numeric' or data_type = 'decimal'
            then '(' + convert(varchar(10), isnull(numeric_precision, 18)) + ',' + convert(varchar(10), isnull(numeric_scale, 0)) + ')'
        when (data_type like '%char' or data_type like '%binary') and character_maximum_length = -1
            then '(max)'
        when character_maximum_length is not null
            then '(' + convert(varchar(10), character_maximum_length) + ')'
        else ''
    end as COLUMN_DEFINITION
FROM information_schema.columns";

using (var db = dbFactory.OpenDbConnection())
{
    var results = db.Dictionary<string,string>(sql + " WHERE table_name = 'Product'");

    var nameColumnDef = results["Name"]; //= varchar(8000)

    //Or print out all column definitions for each field with:
    results.PrintDump();
    /*
    {
        Id: int,
        Name: varchar(8000)
        ...
    }
    */
}
```